# Border crossing (Mexico to U.S.)

Tags: us-residents

I'm an 18-year old resident of the U.S. and I have been all my life. I've spent the past few months in Mexico with family and I'm ready to head home to Michigan. The problem is my mom went back a month ago and never gave me my passport. She's tied up at work and can't bring it to me and won't be able to until Christmas vacation when my siblings get out of school. Are the copies I have of my passport enough for me to cross back into the U.S.?

Comment: There is always FedEx.

Comment: Lesson #1: don't let your mom keep your passport for you.  Are you planning to fly back to the US or travel by land?

Comment: You say you're a "resident of the U.S." Are you a US citizen as well (some people are residents but not citizens)? In other words, is it a US passport?

Comment: Do you have any other sort of ID, such as driver's license?

Comment: Only recently turned 18 and my mom likes to have everything under her control. I'm planning to go by land and yes I have a residency but not a citizenship and yes it is a US passport.

Comment: That's a contradiction - if you have a US passport, you have citizenship.

Comment: @Aganju Not true. Although extremely rare, you can be a US national, with a passport, without citizenship. This includes people born in American Samoa, those who opted out of citizenship conversion from the Northern Mariana Islands, and those born to non-citizen national parents outside of the US. These people can reside and work in the US but cannot vote.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Getting it by mail is nearly impossible in Mexico, the postal service is crap, they lose packages, or often won't give them even though they have arrived. If by any miracle you do get the package then you get it 3-4 months after its sent and the package is damaged.

Comment: I am US resident and so are both of my parents and we were all born in Mexico and have U.S. and Mexican passports. The U.S. one as the little book and the Mexican on as a small card similar to a driver's license. As @user71659 mentioned we can't vote. I've had my residency since I was 2 years old and have visit every year since at least once. Would there be anyway of them looking me up in there system so I can cross?

Comment: @Malvarez00 if you have a US passport then you are a US citizen and you *can* vote. Non-citizen nationals have passports that say "the bearer is a citizen but not a national of the United States." Yours certainly does not say that unless your ancestors are from certain South Pacific islands.  If you are a US permanent resident with a passport-like book issued by the US then that book is not actually a passport.  If that's the case, it will not have the word "passport" on its cover.

Comment: @Malvarez00 FedEx isn't "getting it by mail".

Answer (score 2):

Technically, US citizen must be allowed to enter, even without the passport.

However, the onus is on *you* to prove that you are a US citizen, and that is difficult without a passport and any other papers. You *might* be able to enter, but chances are that they don't believe you, especially at the mexican border.

It is clearly the better approach to get the passport sent by Fed-Ex or similar. It will save you spending a lot of time at the border, potentially being detained, or turned back.